# google-oauth-java How to deal with redirects?

Tags: java, oauth, http-status-code-302

I'm using [google-oauth-java](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/java/) and one thing that really complicates my life is that when I attempt using `OAuthClient.invoke()` I frequently get `OAuthProblemException` thrown due to request returning code 302 instead of 200. Because of that I found myself rewriting `invoke` code and using`OAuthClient.access()` instead. I'm wondering if I'm missing some type of `followRedirect` setting? The documentation is non-existing and examples don't really help, can someone help me here?

Here's snippet from `OAuthClient` to illustrate

```
public OAuthMessage invoke(OAuthMessage request, ParameterStyle style)
        throws IOException, OAuthException {
    OAuthResponseMessage response = access(request, style);
    if ((response.getHttpResponse().getStatusCode() / 100) != 2) {
        OAuthProblemException problem = response.toOAuthProblemException();
        try {
            problem.setParameter(OAuthProblemException.SIGNATURE_BASE_STRING,
                                 OAuthSignatureMethod.getBaseString(request));
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
        throw problem;
    }
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I dealt with this by using `OAuthClient.access()` and nobody is coming forward I'm going to accept my own solution